# How to spawn only 1 item when there is already spawn item

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

i am trying to make a trigger that spawn item but whenever i go in and out its spawn 2 item and i do not now how to make it trigger one only

here the code im using atm

```
public class createobject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Spawnpoint;
    public GameObject Prefab;

    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        
        Debug.Log("Trigger!");
        Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation);
    }

    
      
    // Update is called once per frame

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply storing it:

```c#
private GameObject _currentInstance;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger!");

    if(!_currentInstance)
    {
        _currentInstance = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation);
    }
}
```